# Não consigo retornar valor do Web Service para o PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-service

Já testei o Web service através do SoapUI e ele esta funcionando normalmente retornando os valores.

XML do web service

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ax213="http://appvendas.sata.com.br/xsd" xmlns:ax211="http://sql.java/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://appvendas.sata.com.br" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="http://appvendas.sata.com.br">
<wsdl:documentation>Please Type your service description here</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://sql.java/xsd">
<xs:complexType name="SQLException">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SQLState" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="errorCode" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nextException" nillable="true" type="ax211:SQLException"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:ax214="http://appvendas.sata.com.br/xsd" xmlns:ax212="http://sql.java/xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://appvendas.sata.com.br">
<xs:import namespace="http://sql.java/xsd"/>
<xs:import namespace="http://appvendas.sata.com.br/xsd"/>
<xs:element name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SQLException" nillable="true" type="ax212:SQLException"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="efetuarLogin">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="login" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="senha" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="efetuarLoginResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="ax214:Usuario"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="selUsuario">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="idOrdemCompra" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="login" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="senha" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="selUsuarioResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="true" type="ax214:Usuario"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="inserirUsuario">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="usuario" nillable="true" type="ax214:Usuario"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="inserirUsuarioResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="attUsuario">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="usuario" nillable="true" type="ax214:Usuario"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="attUsuarioResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="excluirUsuario">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="login" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="senha" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="excluirUsuarioResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://appvendas.sata.com.br/xsd">
<xs:complexType name="Infos">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="bairro" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="canc" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="celular" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="complemento" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="conc" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cp" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="idCidadeFK" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="nome" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="numero" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="reputacao" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="rua" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="telefone" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Usuario">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="ax213:Infos">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="login" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="senha" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="efetuarLoginRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:efetuarLogin"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="efetuarLoginResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:efetuarLoginResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="attUsuarioRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:attUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="attUsuarioResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:attUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="excluirUsuarioRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:excluirUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="excluirUsuarioResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:excluirUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="selUsuarioRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:selUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="selUsuarioResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:selUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="inserirUsuarioRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:inserirUsuario"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="inserirUsuarioResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:inserirUsuarioResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="UsuarioDAOPortType">
<wsdl:operation name="efetuarLogin">
<wsdl:input message="ns:efetuarLoginRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:efetuarLogin"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:efetuarLoginResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:efetuarLoginResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault message="ns:UsuarioDAOSQLException" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException" wsaw:Action="urn:efetuarLoginUsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="attUsuario">
<wsdl:input message="ns:attUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:attUsuario"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:attUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:attUsuarioResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault message="ns:UsuarioDAOSQLException" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException" wsaw:Action="urn:attUsuarioUsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="excluirUsuario">
<wsdl:input message="ns:excluirUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:excluirUsuario"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:excluirUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:excluirUsuarioResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault message="ns:UsuarioDAOSQLException" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException" wsaw:Action="urn:excluirUsuarioUsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="selUsuario">
<wsdl:input message="ns:selUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:selUsuario"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:selUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:selUsuarioResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault message="ns:UsuarioDAOSQLException" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException" wsaw:Action="urn:selUsuarioUsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="inserirUsuario">
<wsdl:input message="ns:inserirUsuarioRequest" wsaw:Action="urn:inserirUsuario"/>
<wsdl:output message="ns:inserirUsuarioResponse" wsaw:Action="urn:inserirUsuarioResponse"/>
<wsdl:fault message="ns:UsuarioDAOSQLException" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException" wsaw:Action="urn:inserirUsuarioUsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="UsuarioDAOSoap11Binding" type="ns:UsuarioDAOPortType">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="efetuarLogin">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:efetuarLogin" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="attUsuario">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:attUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="excluirUsuario">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:excluirUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="selUsuario">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:selUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="inserirUsuario">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:inserirUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="UsuarioDAOSoap12Binding" type="ns:UsuarioDAOPortType">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
<wsdl:operation name="efetuarLogin">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:efetuarLogin" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap12:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="attUsuario">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:attUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap12:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="excluirUsuario">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:excluirUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap12:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="selUsuario">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:selUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap12:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="inserirUsuario">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:inserirUsuario" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
<wsdl:fault name="UsuarioDAOSQLException">
<soap12:fault use="literal" name="UsuarioDAOSQLException"/>
</wsdl:fault>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="UsuarioDAOHttpBinding" type="ns:UsuarioDAOPortType">
<http:binding verb="POST"/>
<wsdl:operation name="efetuarLogin">
<http:operation location="efetuarLogin"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="attUsuario">
<http:operation location="attUsuario"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="excluirUsuario">
<http:operation location="excluirUsuario"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="selUsuario">
<http:operation location="selUsuario"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="inserirUsuario">
<http:operation location="inserirUsuario"/>
<wsdl:input>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="UsuarioDAO">
<wsdl:port name="UsuarioDAOHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:UsuarioDAOSoap11Binding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8009/ExemploWS/services/UsuarioDAO.UsuarioDAOHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="UsuarioDAOHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:UsuarioDAOSoap12Binding">
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:8009/ExemploWS/services/UsuarioDAO.UsuarioDAOHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="UsuarioDAOHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:UsuarioDAOHttpBinding">
<http:address location="http://localhost:8009/ExemploWS/services/UsuarioDAO.UsuarioDAOHttpEndpoint/"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Javascript para chamar o metodo post

```
$.post('php/usuarioDAO.php',{usuario: $('#usuario').val(), senha: $('#senha').val()})
                .done( function(dados)
        {
            $('#resposta').html(dados);
        });
```

Codigo PHP

```
<?php

extract($_POST);

$url = "http://localhost:8009/ExemploWS/services/UsuarioDAO?wsdl";

$param = new stdClass;
$param->usuario = $usuario;
$param->senha = $senha;

$soap = @new SoapClient($url, array('exceptions'=>true,'connection_timeout'=>1000));
try
{
    $resposta = $soap->efetuarLogin($param);
        echo "Usuario: ". $resposta->return->nome; //LINHA 17 QUE É CITADA NO ERRO

}catch(Exception $error)
{
    $resposta = $error->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**Mensagem de erro**

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\teste2\php\usuarioDAO.php on line 17 Usuario:

Tentei também com este código

```
 <?php
require_once 'lib/nusoap.php';
$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost:8009/ExemploWS/services/UsuarioDAO?wsdl');

if($client->getError())
{
    echo "erro no construtor".$client->getError();
}
$object = array("login" => "abc","senha"=>"123");
$result = $client->call('efetuarLogin',array('efetuarLogin' => $object));

print_r ($result);

?>
```

mas a mensagem é essa

> Array 
> (
>   [faultcode] => soapenv:Server
>   [faultstring] => namespace
>   mismatch require http://appvendas.sata.com.br found http://tempuri.org
>   [detail] =>  
> )

Comment: A linha 17 é qual? poderia evidenciar ela

Comment: Marquei um comentário no código php onde é a linha 17

Comment: Se der um `print_r()` em `$resposta` vem em branco?

Comment: deu essa mensagem 'stdClass Object ( [return] => )'

Comment: gostaria de saber também como eu posso depurar o código php no netbeans, eu baixei esse "php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.4-vc9-nts.dll" mas nao sei como instala-lo

Comment: vc pode habilitar ele no php.ini, removendo o ponto e virgula dessa linha: `;zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"` depois reinicie o servidor, talvez esse [link](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html) ajude a configurar ele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando o seguinte código

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/nusoap.php';
$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost:8009/ExemploWS/services/UsuarioDAO?wsdl',true);

if($client->getError())
{
    echo "erro no construtor".$client->getError();
}
$object = array("login" => "abc","senha"=>"123");
$result = $client->call('efetuarLogin',array('parameters' => $object));
$obj = $result['return'];
//print_r($result);
echo $obj['nome'];

?>
```

o que faltou foi colocar o TRUE após o endereço do web service, eu usei dois array, por que meu objeto retornava um array dentro do outro, entao so passei o array 'return' para a variavel obj